# ClassCastException when running Spark test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, mockito

I have added mockito (with Guice) to our test environment, like so:

```
class SparkModuleWithMocks extends AbstractModule with JsonFormats {
override def configure(): Unit = {
  //bind(classOf[TrafficFilterRules]).toInstance(trafficFilterRulesMock)
  bind(classOf[TrafficFilterRules]).toProvider(new Provider[TrafficFilterRules]{
    override def get(): TrafficFilterRules = {
      val trafficFilterRulesMock: TrafficFilterRules = mock[TrafficFilterRules](withSettings().serializable())
      val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/trafficFilterRules.json")
      val lines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines.mkString
      val array = parse(lines).extract[List[FilterRules]].toArray
      when(trafficFilterRulesMock.trafficFilterRulesTable).thenReturn(array)
      trafficFilterRulesMock
    }
  })
  bind(classOf[SiteTable]).toProvider(new Provider[SiteTable]{
    override def get(): SiteTable = {
      val siteTableMock: SiteTable = mock[SiteTable](withSettings().serializable())
      val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/siteDomains.json")
      val lines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines.mkString
      val array = parse(lines).extract[List[SiteDomain]].toArray
      when(siteTableMock.siteDomains).thenReturn(array)
      siteTableMock
    }
  })
  bind(classOf[SparkSession]).toProvider(classOf[SparkSessionProvider])
}
}

val injectorWithMocks: Injector = Guice.createInjector(new SparkModuleWithMocks)
```

SparkSessionProvider is our own class that overrides get() for guice and builds sparkSession.
With injectorWithMocks, I inject sparkSession and the services that we test like so:

```
val sparkSession = injector.instance[SparkSession]
val clickoutService = injectorWithMocks.instance[ClickoutEnrichmentService]
```

When I run the test from Intellij, everything works fine but when I run it from sbt command line, for example:

```
 sbt "testOnly *ClickoutEnrichmentServiceTest"
```

I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 49.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in 
stage 49.0 (TID 68, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy 
to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of 
type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

I have read several tickets regarding this issue, but they were all related to running spark cluster, and not local or in test mode.

Can someone please explain what is the cause of this error and what is a good direction to tackle it?

Thanks
Nir

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this. I eventually found this question [Mockito's mock throw ClassNotFoundException in Spark application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336383/mockitos-mock-throw-classnotfoundexception-in-spark-application) from @K.Chen

He provides a solution for his problem, namely, use 
`mock[SiteTable](withSettings().serializable(SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS))` instead in your code. That is, pass the extra param `SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS`

Unfortunately, as pointed in his question, he's unsure of why this resolves things.

In the source code of `SerializableMode` in Mockito 2.13.1 we find the following comment:

    `/**
     * Useful if the mock is deserialized in a different classloader / vm.
     */
    @Incubating
    ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS`

[source](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/mock/SerializableMode.java#L26)

Perhaps the classloader in the executors vs. master is different?