# How to create a Spark RDD of mocked elements?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mockito, hbase, rdd

I'd like to create an RDD (an actual one, not mocked) that contains mocked elements (with Mockito) in a unit test.

My attempt is:

```
lazy val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq( (Mockito.mock(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable]), Mockito.mock(classOf[Result])) ))
```

where `ImmutableBytesWritable` and `Result` come from HBase API.
I got `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Is there any way possible to achieve my goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Mockito mocks are not serializable, that's why you get the error.

To create serializable mocks, you have to define it explicitly :

```scala
mock = Mockito.mock(
    classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
    Mockito.withSettings().serializable()
)
```

The same thing should be applied to your `Result` mock.

In case you got a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable$MockitoMock$...` exception, you might need to use :

```scala
import org.mockito.mock.SerializableMode

mock = Mockito.mock(
    classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
    Mockito.withSettings().serializable(SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS)
)
```

Finally, you should have something like :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf    

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.mock.SerializableMode

object Test extends App {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[2]")
        .setAppName("test")
    lazy val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val mockImmutableBytesWritable = Mockito.mock(
        classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
        Mockito.withSettings().serializable(
            SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS
        )
    )

    val mockResult = Mockito.mock(
        classOf[Result],
        Mockito.withSettings().serializable(
            SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS
        )
    )

    val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq((mockImmutableBytesWritable, mockResult)))

    println(myRDD.count)

    sc.stop()

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still got the same error. Could you see if this is correct?
    `val mockImmutableBytesWritable = Mockito.mock(
      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
      Mockito.withSettings().serializable()
    )`
    `val mockResult = Mockito.mock(
      classOf[Result],
      Mockito.withSettings().serializable()
    )`
    `val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq((mockImmutableBytesWritable, mockResult)))`

Comment: I have reproduced your example, but got a different error (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable$MockitoMock$...`) when using `Mockito.withSettings().serializable()` and doing a simple `myRDD.count`. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336383/mockitos-mock-throw-classnotfoundexception-in-spark-application) fixing it, so you might need to add `SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS` in the Mockito settings (see my edited answer).

Comment: Thank you so much! Did it work on your machine? What's the version number for your Mockito dependency?

Comment: @Nightingale Yes I have reproduced your issue locally with a simple example.  I'm using `mockito-core:2.21.0`, `hbase-client:1.4.6`, `hbase-common:1.4.6` and `spark-core:2.3.0`. I've updated my answer with the sample code I used.