# Cannot load user class: org.mockito.codegen.RestUtil when mocked class is used in flink testcase

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am having flink task and test spec like below. This testcase properly working as expected in Intellij. But, when running in Terminal `mvn clean install`, throws the `org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class: org.mockito.codegen.mockHttpUtil`

FlinkTask.scala

```scala
class FlinkTask(config: TaskConfig, httpUtil: HttpUtil) {
  def process(): Unit = {
    implicit val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = FlinkUtil.getExecutionContext(config)
    env.addSource(kafkaConnector.source(config.kafkaInputTopic)).name(config.eventConsumer)
      .rebalance
      .process(new TaskProcessFunction(config, httpUtil))
      .name(config.taskProcessFunction)
      .uid(config.taskProcessFunction)
      .setParallelism(config.parallelism)
    
    env.execute(config.jobName)
  } 
}

object FlinkTask {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = new TaskConfig("config.path")
    val httpUtil: HttpUtil = new HttpUtil
    task = new FlinkTask(config, httpUtil)
    task.process()
  }
}
```

TaskProcessFunction.scala

```scala
class TaskProcessFunction(config: TaskConfig, httpUtil: HttpUtil) extends ProcessFunction[String, String] {
  override def processElement(event: String, context: ProcessFunction[String, String]#Context, out: Collector[String]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

HttpUtil.scala

```scala
class HttpUtil extends Serializable {

  def get(url: String, headers: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String]("Content-Type"->"application/json")): HttpResponse = {
    Unirest.get(url).headers(headers.asJava).asString() // returns HttpResponse
  }
}
```

FlinkTaskTestSpec.scala

```scala
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.scalatestplus.mockito.MockitoSugar

class FlinkTaskTestSpec extends BaseTestSpec with MockitoSugar {
  val jobConfig = new TaskConfig("testconfig.path")
  val mockHttpUtil = mock[HttpUtil](Mockito.withSettings().serializable())

  "FlinkTask" should "generate event" in {
    when(mockHttpUtil.get(contains("url"), any())).thenReturn(HttpResponse(200, "responsejson"))
    new FlinkTask(jobConfig, mockHttpUtil).process()
  }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
 Cause: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class: org.mockito.codegen.HttpUtil$MockitoMock$1840807158
ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
Class not resolvable through given classloader.
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:322)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:146)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:485)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:531)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:722)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:547)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.codegen.HttpUtil$MockitoMock$1840807158
  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336383/mockitos-mock-throw-classnotfoundexception-in-spark-application

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't exactly provide the solution for the mock related problem, I really believie that You should avoid mocking whenever it's possible, especially in cases like that when You are going to serialize the mocked class.

You can easily avoid this by simply making `FlinkTask` take a trait that could have two implementations one for actual usage and the other for testing say `TestHttpUtil` that would basically be a stub.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dominik Wosiński . Creating a trait could work in one way. Since HttpUtil is being used in other modules also, I don't want to make multiple HttpUtil implementations. I believe this is happening because flink's dynamic classloader. Could you help me with this?